# Can swagger handle IEnumerable of string in Http requests?

Tags: c#, swagger

I'm pretty new to web development and swagger in general so apologies if the question is too naive.

I'll use the *Asp.Net Core Web Api* template in visual studio 2019 to better explain my problem, so please consider that environment in the case I have omitted some information (or just ask for the missing part that I'll bring it).

There we have the `WeatherForecastController` class with a simple GET (which I included the `names` parameter):

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    //...
}
```

When I try to test this request using the Swagger page, it doesn't recognize the `name` parameter.

I have ran other tests to find out what's going on and I found the following:

1. Swagger does work with IEnumerable as it works pretty well if the parameter is of type `IEnumerable<IFormFile>` (it displays a list of uploaded files, shows the file selection dialog, etc);
2. I tried encapsulating the parameter(s) in a *DTO* class and it seems to break even more stuff (even the `IEnumerable<IFormFile>` doesn't seem to work inside a *DTO* class; it only works if passed directly in the parameter list of the `[HttpVerb]` method;
3. I tried with other similar types as well as `ICollection<string>`, `List<string>`, `string[]`; none of them seem to work;
4. This same problem happens using primitive types like `bool`, `int`, etc as type arguments to `IEnumerable<T>`;

So what is happening? Should I set some sort of configuration value so it can work with collections of primitive types?

**Update with images showing the problem:**

`... Get(string names, IEnumerable<IFormFile> file)`:
[image]

`... Get(IEnumerable<string> names, IFormFile file)`:
[image]

As you can see, when any parameter in the param list is of IEnumerable the swagger UI doesn't properly show the requested fields like in the second image.

Comment: what query string did you try with this?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 the problem is not with the query string, the problem is in using the swagger UI to assembly the query string, I'll update the question with a print screen showing the problem in a minute.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 just updated the question with 2 images showing when it goes right and when it goes wrong.

Comment: Add [FromBody] attribute before you array parameter. I think  Swagger UI does not handle array parameters correctly when in formData.

Comment: @AliReza encapsulating it in a DTO class and using `[FromForm]` did the trick, thanks! Do you want to put that in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify model binding sources in your case. Your action method should be like this:

```
    [HttpPost("test/names")]
    public IEnumerable<string> PostNames([FromQuery]IEnumerable<string> names, IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
    {
        //...some code
        return names;
    }
```

You shouldn't use two or more complex type parameter as an action parameters until you specify the source they are binding from. That's because complex objects are bound to [request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#frombody-attribute) by default and only one parameter can be bound to request body.

As of microsoft docs :

> Don't apply `[FromBody]` to more than one parameter per action method. Once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other `[FromBody]` parameters.

Complex type means class variables, arrays, and those which are not primary types like `int`,`double`, `string` and etc.

Swagger generates this UI for action above:

[image]

As the final word , Note that you can't send something in your request body when you are using `GET` http request.